# How to set default register in a database table with EntityFramework Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying create a system using `EntityFramework` code first for connect my database, I'm using code first, because I want it create database and tables automatic if not exist.

So, I want when my `Logins` table is created, it insert a first register, user Admin and password Admin

How to I do this?

My code:

```
public class Login
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class MySystemContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called seeding a database, have a look [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx) for a brief tutotial. Julie Lerman also has a blog post on it [here](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/seeding-a-database-with-ef4-code-first/).